# Joining two table without relantioships in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Here is my problem. I have three tables.

One called Project which has only one Column called id (this must be unique throughout the system).
One called ServiceAwarenessProject which has a one to one relationship with Project.id.
One called CorporateVPNProject which has a one to one relationship with Project.id

I'm using sqlalchemy ORM, so the code looks like the one below:

```
class Project(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class ServiceAwarenessProject(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'sa_project'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Project.id))
    mop_url = Column(String, nullable=False)
    expiration_date = Column(Datetime, index=True)


class CorporateVPNProject(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'wvpn_project'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Project.id))
    mop_url = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

I designed my tables like that, so I can guarantee I have unique project_ids in the entire system. My problem is that I don't know how to join those tables together to find a project based on the project_id. To solve this problem for now, I'm querying both tables, using the function called get_project_by_id.
Is there a smarter way to solve this issue?

```
class ProjectService:
    @staticmethod
    def create_project_id():
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        result = session.query(Project.id).order_by(desc(Project.id)).first()

        if result:
            result = result[0]
            if str(result)[:8] == datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'):
                project_id = str(result)[:8] + '{:03d}'.format(int(str(result)[8:]) + 1)
                new_project = Project(id=project_id)
                session.add(new_project)
                session.commit()
                return project_id

        project_id = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '001'
        new_project = Project(id=project_id)
        session.add(new_project)
        session.commit()
        return project_id

    @staticmethod
    def get_project_by_id(project_id):
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        result = session.query(ServiceAwarenessProject) \
            .filter(ServiceAwarenessProject.project_id == project_id) \
            .first()

        if result:
            return result

        result = session.query(CorporateVPNProject) \
            .filter(CorporateVPNProject.project_id == project_id) \
            .first()
        if result:
            return result

    def create_serviceawareness_project(self):
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        project_id = self.create_project_id()
        new_project = ServiceAwarenessProject(project_id=project_id, mop_url='http://www.thepacketwizards.com/1')
        session.add(new_project)
        session.commit()
        return new_project

    def create_corporatevpn_project(self):
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        project_id = self.create_project_id()
        new_project = CorporateVPNProject(project_id=project_id, mop_url='http://www.thepacketwizards.com/wvpn')
        session.add(new_project)
        session.commit()
        return new_project
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly would you like `get_project_by_id()` to do? As it is now it'll return either a ServiceAwarenessProject instance, CorporateVPNProject instance, or None. You don't need relationship attributes for joins. Relationship attributes are an ORM concept, though they can be used in forming joins as well when making queries.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'd like this function to return exactly what it's returning right now, either ServiceAwarenessProject instance, CorporateVPNProject instance or None. I'm just asking if there is a smarter way to do it. Because right now if the project_id I'm looking for doesn't exists on ServiceAwarenessProject table I'll have to do another query.

Comment: Ah I finally get what you're after. Though some dislike them, you could've perhaps used the [inheritance patterns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html) provided by SQLAlchemy. That'd make what you're trying to do rather simple. You'd also get to keep your unique project_id guarantee. What you have now is close to [concrete table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance), with a touch of [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance).

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look into that!

Comment: @IljaEverilä Could you help me with my new question? Could anyone help me figure out to print the columns of the row I found with `get_project_by_id`? I mean, I tried using __table__.column, but it doesn't return the columns from inherited Class. My goal now is to iterate the query like a dictionary, like so: `for result in query:  print(key, result[key]`). Is it possible? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Following @Ilja Everilä suggestion, I designed the table like so, using only [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance).

```
class Project(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
    project_url = Column(String(60))
    mop_url = Column(String(60))
    input_url = Column(String(60))
    type = Column(String(60))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'project',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class ServiceAwarenessProject(Project):
    __tablename__ = 'sa_project'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('project.id'), primary_key=True)
    expiration_date = Column(DateTime)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'ServiceAwareness',
    }


class CorporateVPNProject(Project):
    __tablename__ = 'wvpn_project'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('project.id'), primary_key=True)
    client_name = Column(String(60))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'CorporateVPN',
    }
```

Now, to query the DB I have to use `with_polymorphic`, so I can get different instances of Tables per row.

```
class ProjectService:
    @staticmethod
    def create_project_id():
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        result = session.query(Project.id).order_by(desc(Project.id)).first()
        print(result)
        if result:
            result = result[0]
            if str(result)[:8] == datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'):
                project_id = str(result)[:8] + '{:03d}'.format(int(str(result)[8:]) + 1)
                return project_id

        project_id = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '001'
        return project_id

    def create_serviceawareness_project(self):
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        project_id = self.create_project_id()
        new_project = ServiceAwarenessProject(id=project_id,
                                              project_url='http://project',
                                              expiration_date=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=365),
                                              mop_url='http://mop',
                                              input_url='http://url',
                                              type='ServiceAwareness')

        session.add(new_project)
        session.commit()
        session.add(new_project)

        return new_project

    def create_corporatevpn_project(self):
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        project_id = self.create_project_id()
        new_project = CorporateVPNProject(id=project_id,
                                          project_url='http://project',
                                          client_name='TIM',
                                          mop_url='http://mop',
                                          input_url='http://url',
                                          type='CorporateVPN')

        session.add(new_project)
        session.commit()
        session.add(new_project)

        return new_project

    @staticmethod
    def get_project_by_id(project_id):
        session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()
        query = session.query(with_polymorphic(Project, [ServiceAwarenessProject, CorporateVPNProject])).filter(or_(
            ServiceAwarenessProject.id == project_id,
            CorporateVPNProject.id == project_id
        )).first()
        return query
```

Comment: Could anyone help me figure out to print the columns of the row I found with `get_project_by_id`? I mean, I tried using __table__.column, but it doesn't return the columns from inherited Class. My goal now is to iterate the query like a dictionary, like so: `for result in query:  print(key, result[key]`). Is it possible? Thanks..